# Choice of $N_{terms}$, frequency grid in Lomb-Scargle periodogram

Tags: sampling, nyquist, periodogram

*I am completely new to signal processing! Please explain as if speaking to someone who knows nothing more than linear algebra and what a Fourier transform is defined as.*

I am working with an 8-month timeseries of data, sampled at 15-min intervals (at least for the present variable of interest). The data is from a real-world ocean setting, so there are discrete events, lasting days to weeks, when no data is recorded. I want to get either a frequency or a power density spectrum of my data, to understand the timescales at which my variable changes. Given the discontinuity of the data, I wish to use a Lomb-Scargle periodogram (am currently using the `astropy` implementation). Please help me out with the following questions:

1. As I understand it, the general problem in spectral analysis is to (a) choose a set of frequencies $\{f_i\}$ that somehow form an ideal basis for our data, and (b) to perform least-squares regression to find ideal coefficients for $\{sin(f_it), cos(f_it)\}$. For evenly-sampled data with a particular choice of $\{f_i\}$, this is the DFT - it comes out to be matrix multiplication by a diagonal matrix; that is, the computation of coefficients for one frequency do not depend on the others! For uneven data, other off-diagonal terms should turn up, but Lomb-Scargle with $N_{terms}=1$ drops the correlations between frequencies and solves frequency by frequency anyway. *Firstly, is this interpretation correct? If so, is the Lomb-Scargle solution nonunique? Specifically, won't I see peaks in the periodogram at  every higher harmonic of the actual frequency? Is the integral of the periodogram not guaranteed to give the power of the actual signal because the measure of the original function is not simply reshuffled from the time-domain to the frequency-domain, but may instead attribute the contribution of a single frequncy to multiple? What then is the disadvantage to increasing $N_{terms}$, or even simply carrying out a full least-squares regression*?
2. What is the Nyquist factor? I (think I) understand that Shannon and Nyquist's theorem says we should sample at twice the highest frequency of interest. Since my data is sampled at a quarter-hourly frequency, the design of our experiment has already assumed that once every 30 minutes is the highest frequency of interest (actually, since the theorem is a strict ineqality, that it is higher than every frequency of interest). Does astropy's 'Nyquist factor' argument allow me to change the '2' in the S-N theorem into a '5' or other factor? If I set the Nyquist factor to 5, in my case, what would the highest frequency be? Given that the discontinuities in my data are not random samples, but occasional instrument blackouts, does it make sense to deviate from the standard Nyquist frequency?
3. Finally, what is the argument for a uniform frequency grid versus a uniform period grid or any arbitrary grid of frequencies between my lowest (once every 4 months?) and highest frequencies of interest? How can I avoid missing frequencies that carry a lot of information simply because they are not on my grid? Is there a standard best-practice?

In case it is relevant, the periodograms I have made so far of a two-month stretch of the data (without blackouts) show a sharp peak at 12-hours (tidal effects, probably, as the data is from the ocean) and broad peaks elsewhere.